# Is a stator another word for a soft iron core?

Tags: core, stator

Pretty much a yes or no question. Would be greatly appreciated thankyou

Comment: Googling this would have been better.

Comment: Pretty much, the answer is NO.

Comment: I tried googling for ages and nothing specific came up

Comment: A stator MAY consist of  soft-iron and may be a core BUT most stators are not soft iron and stators are many tings besides cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't. We can find soft iron core in transformers and electric magnets where word stator is meaningless.

Stator is the non-moving part around (see NOTE1) the rotating part (=rotor) in an electric motor or generator. Actually stator contains only those non-moving windings and their iron core which interact magnetically with the rotor. Stator and rotor often have soft iron core for magnetic effectiveness, the flux will be stronger and better placed with it. But soft iron core isn't a must.

Stator hasn't always windings, many small motors are made with permanent magnets in stator. Soft iron can still be used to direct the magnetic flux better.

BTW. Soft iron core is common also in knives, often there's hard steel only on the surface.

NOTE1: There's a comment which says that stator isn't allways around the rotor. That's true.Nothing prevents having the rotor as an outer ring around the non-rotating stator. More: there exists rotating electric machines where the rotor and stator aren't coaxial. An example: The unipolar motor which was common in kWh-meters before modern remote readable electronic meters.

Historically remarkable invention was Hippolyte Pixii's generator (about. 1832), where stator and rotor were coaxial, but they were face to face, neither was inside the other:

[image]

Comment: Omg thankyou so much, this has been very helpful

Comment: @Liv user287001 is not God and use of comments of that sort are better avoided.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I think the questioner only wrote of his surprise "was it that simple!", there's not a word about me.  Anyway, the comment isn't technical, so it's offtopic.

Comment: @user287001 :-) - Yes. I was being flippant - but, with a point. Using such terms or text speech or slang tends to be frowned on and is far better avoided if people want to be treated  seriously by others. || FWIW the biggest indicator of low quality questions is, according to upper upper management here, use of ALL CAPITALS.

Comment: @user287001 Technical point - you know this but you may wish to qualify it for others. "Stator is the non moving part" - not just "inside". RC motors are classed as inrunners and outrunners . A Fisher & Paykel Smart drive BLDCM has the stator inside. ....

Comment: @user287001 No. It takes no more effort for you to edit it, should you wish to,  as to reply to me. I try to not edit answers where people say what they mean and mean what they say. I find it annoying when people change my answers to ones that corrupt my original intentions. Far better, I think, for you to decide if you agree with me and if you do to change the answer in such a way that it says what you want to convey. Your answer is a good one and I do not think it worth adding a new answer over one useful but minor point.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the answer is fixed.

Comment: @user287001 Your " Hippolyte Pixii's generator" picture had me puzzled for a moment. At first I though that the mangents protruded into the coils, which made no sense. Then I realised that (of course) the magnets spun against but not touching the pile faces of the coils. This is a nice  example of an early axial flux alternator. The coils lie in a plane parallel to the magnet plane.

Comment: The similarity with modern [**axial flux alternators**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1680&bih=907&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=nuadXKX7JJr0rQGmtaLADA&q=axial+flux+alternator&oq=axial+flux+alternator&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24l3.9176.10895..12255...0.0..0.182.1033.0j6......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30.Y_fLxN8Bojk) can be seen here.